# My exe file is autoclosing after start

Tags: vmware, c#

I wrote application in c# and when I try to open it on VM (vmware 15.1) in task manager i can see that it starts, then changes status to stopped and then autoclosed. I need to add that when I try to open this .exe file on my main computer it works and the same situation is when I'm trying to open it from shared folder (VMware). Other exe files works normally. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: C# is just a programming language. Did you create a desktop application? A UWP application? A Windows service? VMware doesn’t run programs. The OS in the VM does. What’s the OS? Where are you seeing this status?

Comment: I solved the problem. My program required external library and i didnt copy it from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a dependancy issue, ensure you have things like .Net Framework on your target machine, and that your application is building with the appropriate version of the framework targeted. You could add some debug logging to your application to prove that this is the case.